# Update table value tought vba access

Tags: database, ms-access

I have the following microsoft access vba code I want to use to update a table called tb_users.
The table has 4 columns (Id, username,password,firstlogindate).

```
Dim db as database
Dim MySQL as string
Set db= currentdb

If isnull(firstlogindate) =true then
    Mysql = Update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where username =" & chr(34) & cbousername & chr(34)
    Execute db.mysql
Endif
```

But I get the following error: [Expecting end of statement] with this line.  Mysql = Update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where username =" & chr(34) & cbousername & chr(34)     highlighted in red.

What is wrong with the code?
Is there a better way of achieving the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss some quotes - or use single quotes:

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim MySQL As String
Set db= CurrentDb

If IsNull(firstlogindate) = True Then
    MySQL = "update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where username = '" & cbousername & "'"
    db.Execute MySQL
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Mysql = "Update tblusers set firstlogindate = date() where username ='" & cbousername & "'"
db.Execute Mysql, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey.